# What is the equivalent way for BASE64Encoder(Java) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

Should I use npm package like *crypto-js* ?

```
String hash = "Something" ;
hash = (new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder()).encode(sha.digest(hash.getBytes()));
```

**Edit:**

Suggestions led to different results. I have found the solution as below on server side with nodejs:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const hashStr = "Something different";
let sha = crypto.createHash('sha1');
sha.update(hashStr);
let shaBase64 = sha.digest('base64');

console.log(shaBase64);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `window.btoa` function for that.

```
btoa('Something');
```